# Want to avoid the particular rows from select join query... See description

Tags: mysql, select, left-join

I have a Select Left Join Query whis displays me the rows for the latest changedone(its a time) column name ("field" should not be equal) column name ("trackid" should not be equal), and column name "Operation should be "UPDATE" ", below is the query I am talking about...

```
SELECT j1. *
FROM jos_audittrail j1
LEFT OUTER JOIN jos_audittrail j2 ON ( j1.trackid != j2.trackid
AND j1.field != j2.field
AND j1.changedone < j2.changedone )
WHERE j1.operation = 'UPDATE'
AND j2.id IS NULL
```

I get the result with field value as either "lastvisitDate" or "hits"

Now here I don't want a row to be displayed with a two particular column's value i.e. "field's value" the value is "lastvisitDate" and "hits"

Now if i append the condition in the above query that 
" AND j1.field != 'lastvistDate' AND j1.field != 'hits' "
then i do not get any result...

The table structure is

jos_audittrail:

1. id
2. trackid
3. operation
4. oldvalue
5. newvalue
6. table_name
7. live
8. changedone(its a time)

I hope i have given the details properly If u still find something missing I will try to provide it more better way...

Pls help me to avoid those two rows with those to mentioned value of "field"

Comment: Can you give an example of the output you get before adding the clauses that don't work?

Comment: I am firing this query to get the latest change done for the update operation...which is recorded in the jos_audittrail table according to the table structure i have described above...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Changed My select query this way and I got the result the way I needed

```
SELECT j1. *
FROM jos_audittrail j1
LEFT OUTER JOIN jos_audittrail j2 ON ( j1.trackid != j2.trackid
AND j1.field = j2.field
AND j1.changedone < j2.changedone )
WHERE j1.operation = 'UPDATE'
AND j2.id IS NULL AND j1.field != 'lastvisitDate' AND j1.field != 'hits'
```

Thanks Pranav For the Support... :)